# How to remove paragraph spacing in output using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Library

Tags: c#, desktop-application

In my C# Desktop app i am using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` library to write to a word file. But whenever its done exporting there's huge spaces between paragraphs. Using the `paragraph1.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0;` parameter doesn't affect the result as well. 
My desired result is the "No Spacing" preset in Word but after some research i found out it is not an option this library. 
Is there any way to remove or set the spacing between paragraphs.
This is my code:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Application();
 word.Visible = false;
 var doc = word.Documents.Add();
 var paragraph1 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();

 paragraph1.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri";
 paragraph1.Range.Font.Size = 11;

 paragraph1.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0;
 paragraph1.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0;

 paragraph1.Range.Text = story;
 paragraph1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

 doc.SaveAs2(@"F:\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\LITPC\LITPC\bin\Debug\"+title+".docx");

 word.Quit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the `SpaceBefore` and `SpaceAfter` properties take floats so you need to suffix your values with an f.
Try: `paragraph1.SpaceBefore = 0.0f;`, that worked for me.

Also, be careful to reset the spacing when you insert a new paragraph because subsequent paragraphs will inherit the new spacing.

Or avoid Interop Word altogether if you can, it's a deep, dark, rabbit hole I've been down for several days.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing the `Word.Paragraph.SpaceAfter` parameter on previous paragraph. For example.

```
// First Paragraph
Word.Paragraph mainTitle = document.Paragraphs.Add();
mainTitle.Range.Text = "para1";
mainTitle.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
mainTitle.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
mainTitle.SpaceAfter = 0.0f;

// Second Paragraph
Word.Paragraph semiTitle = document.Paragraphs.Add();
semiTitle.Range.Text = "para2";
semiTitle.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
semiTitle.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
semiTitle.SpaceAfter = 10.0f;
```

So, the `SpaceAfter` of `semiTitle` will be 0. Similarly, the `SpaceAfter` of the next paragraph after `semiTitle` will be 10.